# html constrain box-model of image to the area it covers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a square image inside a rectangular div of variable aspect ratio. I set its property object-fit: contain; with the idea that it would dynamically resize to fill the div but not exceed it. This works as intended. However, I have an imagemap to go along with it, and here is where the problem is: The boxmodel for the image extends out to fill the rectangular div, despite the actual image only taking up a portion of it. Is there any way I can either constrain the boxmodel to only take up the space the image uses, or to somehow get information about that space in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: We need your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `width: 100%`, `height: 100%` and `object-fit: cover` or, the better option, `background-image`, `background-size: cover` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

```css
.img-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
}

#img1 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#img2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<p>Use background (the better option)</p>
<div class="img-container" id="img1"></div>

<br>

<p>Use full width/height and object-fit</p>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/200" id="img2">
</div>
```

**Learn about these here:**

First solution:

- [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)
- [background size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)
- [background repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

Second solution:

- [width & height (sizing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS)
- [object fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)